# What is the name for a ring without nilpotent elements?

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

Let $n,m$ be positive integers.

What is the name for a ring $A$ that satisfies the two conditions :

---

$1)$ The ring $A$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb R}^{n}\times{\Bbb C}^{m}$.

$2)$ For every nonzero element $q$ of $A$ we have $q^2 \neq 0$.

---

I know that condition 2 is referred to as " no nilpotent elements " but I assume there is better terminology than " nilpotentfree $A$ iso  ${\Bbb R}^{n}\times{\Bbb C}^{m} $" or something like that.

Comment: A ring without nilpotents is called *reduced*

Comment: 1. The title doesn't really fit to the question. 2.  user115654 has answered the question in the title. 3. I don't think that there is a special name for rings of the form $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n$. 4. Notice that this already implies that the ring is reduced. So in your notation 2) follows from 1).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I do not think 2) follows from 1) if $n >> m.$

Comment: Why? A field is reduced, and a product of reduced rings is reduced. Both are trivial facts.

Comment: A field has no zero-divisors ! The rings given here can have zero-divisors. @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: I know that. The ring is a product of fields, and these are always reduced (in fact, every reduced commutative ring is a subring of a product of fields).

Comment: ? If a ring is a product of fields and those are Always reduced why do we have reduced and unreduced rings then ?

I can imagine R^5 having nilpotent elements so 2) does not follow from 1) as you said ??

Comment: @mick Are you under the impression that every ring is a product of fields somehow?

Comment: @rschwieb Euh I though he said that.

Comment: @mick He's saying "a product of fields never has nonzero nilpotents, so 2 is redundant.." That's what you're describing right? rings that are products of copies of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Oh, I also see now he pointed out that *reduced* rings are subrings of products of fields. That's true also... maybe you overlooked the italicized "reduced"? :)

Comment: Semisimple commutative real algebra :-)

Comment: @rschwieb my knowledge is limited. Show me how R^5 contains no nilpotents !?

Comment: Hint: If an element in a product of rings is nilpotent then each one of its coordinates must be zero or nilpotent.

Comment: @mick Much more is true. Any product of nonzero reduced rings is reduced. It's really elementary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condition 1 completely characterizes the class of commutative [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_algebra) $\Bbb R$ algebras (with sensible restrictions, like $m,n$ both nonnegative integers, at most one zero.)

And to echo  user115654's and Martin's important comments, rings without nilpotent elements are called [*reduced*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring), and indeed products of fields are all reduced, so the second condition is superfluous.